# jQuery - click event in and after another click event

Tags: jquery, jquery-click-event

I want to activate a click event only after another click event has occurred.

Here is my current code :

```
$('#mydiv').click(function(){
    //some code
    $('body').click(function(e){
      if($(e.target).is('#mydiv2'))return;
          //some code
    });
 });
```

### Update :

- I have 2 Div's: #mydiv and #mydiv2
- The second Div (#mydiv2) is hidden.
- When I click on #mydiv I want to show #mydiv2.
- When I click anywhere else on the page I want to hide #mydiv2

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Please be clear of the problem.

Comment: This statement is very confusing: But when I click on #mydiv both click events will trigger. I want second click events trigger just if i clicked on #mydiv first.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/W8rDM/3/ added below. You click anywhere and it closes. if this is not correct, I strongly suggest you  reword your question *carefully* as you do not explain your requirements clearly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply disable and re-enable the click event on `#mydiv2` (to ensure it is only connected once and not every time you enable it).

### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/W8rDM/

```
$('#mydiv').click(function () {
    $('#mydiv2').off('click').on('click', function () {
        alert('#mydiv2 clicked!');
    });
    alert("mydiv2 activated!");
});
```

### Update: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/W8rDM/1/

Based on your new comment (about showing/hiding the second div), you can do something like this:

```
$('#mydiv').click(function () {
    $('#mydiv2').off('click').on('click', function () {
        alert('#mydiv2 clicked!');
        $(this).hide();
    }).show();
    alert("mydiv2 activated!");
});
```

As you just want to hide and show a second div, which can only be clicked when visible, you can do something much simpler that originally thought. Just hook up the two events and hide/show the second div:

### Simplified: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/W8rDM/2/

```
$('#mydiv').click(function () {
    $('#mydiv2').show();
});

$('#mydiv2').on('click', function () {
    $(this).hide();
})
```

### Last attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/W8rDM/3/

As you want to show it when you click the first div and hide the second div when you click anywhere, this should do the trick:

```
$('#mydiv').click(function (e) {
    $('#mydiv2').show();
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).on('click', function () {
    $('#mydiv2').hide();
})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.But I want hide it if I clicked out of the #mydiv2.

Comment: I know and I'm sorry for that.my English explanation is a little weak.

Comment: "weak" not "wick" :) Does the final version do what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#mydiv').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    // code for mydiv
});
$('body').click(function(e){
   // code for body
});
```